# Can't access logically partitioned HDD

Tags: gparted

I am not able to access my whole HDD. I use only 31GB of 160GB. GParted shows me my disk and the partitions but I am not able to mount it. It shows me following:

[image]

Please help me. How can I recover my HDD?

Comment: There is a red exclamation mark (!) next to your /dev/sda5 partition. It would help if you told us what it says!

Comment: The filesystem on the extended partition is an encrypted filesystem. How are you trying to mount it? Do you have the access code for it?  (LUKS crypt -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup )